# font showing as solid rectangle, using slick2d/opengl

Tags: java, opengl, slick2d

Learning 3d java programming, and I've built a block-based 3d world map (minecraft-clone lesson). I have a texture loaded for properly rendering the block sides.

I'm trying to display debug text to the screen (which I've done in a 2d game just fine). However, the text appears either using the texture for the blocks, or it appears completely black - no text.

I've tried a dozen variations of preventing the texture from being used, but nothing solves the above problems.

Used before drawing the text:

```
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0, 1, -1);
    //glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();

    arialPlain.drawString(20, 20, "ON BLOCK:" + strBlock, Color.black);

    // Restore the state of the projection mode
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();

    // Restore the state of the model view mode
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

The text always renders as a black (whatever font color I've chosen) rectangle, none of the actual text characters are shown.

Comment: Call `glEnable (GL_TEXTURE_2D)` ***before*** `arialPlain.drawString (...)`. As for binding the proper texture for this operation to work, Slick's `TrueTypeFont` class should do that - look at the implementation [here](https://bitbucket.org/kevglass/slick/src/9d7443ec33af/trunk/Slick/src/org/newdawn/slick/TrueTypeFont.java), it does everything needed to draw the text except for enable `GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

Comment: Tried that as well. The system has GL_TEXTURE_2D on already to properly render the sides of the blocks. Turning it off and the world turns white. The font still shows as a black square.